# Is there a way other than using dataset for xml reading

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I basically just want to read the xml into horseracing class. I have this code but (List)rows[1] always returns 0

```
public List<HorseRacing> ReturnListOfHorseRacings()
    {
        string xmlData = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/top.xml");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(xmlData);
        var horseRacing = new List<HorseRacing>();
        horseRacing = (from rows in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                       select new HorseRacing
                       {
                           name= rows[0].ToString(),
                           meetings= (List<Meeting>)rows[1],
                       }).ToList();
        return horseRacing;
    }
```

Please help. It seems like Dataset cell cannot accept a list.

By the way, Meeting is also another multi-element node.

Edit:

The xml looks like this:

```
<horseracing>
  <name>UK / IRE</name>
  <meetings>
    <meeting>
      <name>Doncaster</name>
       <marketgroups>
        <marketgroup>
          <name>5f Cond Stakes</name>
           <idfwmarketgroup>468262.1</idfwmarketgroup>
           <tsstart>2013-03-22T13:25:00</tsstart>
        </marketgroup>
        <marketgroup>
          <name>1m 2 1/2f Handicap</name>
          <idfwmarketgroup>468263.1</idfwmarketgroup>
          <tsstart>2013-03-22T14:00:00</tsstart>
        </marketgroup>
       </marketgroups>
     </meeting>
    <meeting>
      <name>Newbury</name>
       <marketgroups>
        <marketgroup>
          <name>2m 5f 0y Emma Lavelle Racing Maiden Hurdle</name>
           <idfwmarketgroup>468270.1</idfwmarketgroup>
           <tsstart>2013-03-22T14:10:00</tsstart>
         </marketgroup>
        <marketgroup>
           <name>2m 6f 110y Mark Polding Half Century Handicap Chase</name>
          <idfwmarketgroup>468271.1</idfwmarketgroup>
          <tsstart>2013-03-22T14:40:00</tsstart>
        </marketgroup>
      </marketgroups>
    </meeting>
  </meetings>
 </horseracing>
```

sorry.
Edit part II:
I want to read the xml into a horseraceing class.

Comment: why even use Dataset here. why not use linq to xml?

Comment: sorry I am new to xml and this is the first thing i found

Comment: "Meeting is another multi-element node" - It's hard to have any idea what your XML looks like if you don't show us an example.

Comment: It also depends on what you are doing with the XML as to how you want to read it. There are readers that are forward-only for streaming the entire document, readers that allow you to navigate around. Are you loading it or querying for a specific part of it? If we understand this we can target the answer more appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read an XML file using an XDocument. The XDocument requires an XML feed, that in turn needs a string feed. In code, it would look something like this:

```
XDocument coordinates = XDocument.Load (XmlReader.Create (new StringReader (File.ReadAllText (pathOfFile))));
```

You can then loop through the XDocument using a foreach-loop:

```
foreach (var coordinate in coordinates.Descendants("document")) 
{
    string data = coordinate.Element ("object").Value;
}
```

"Descendants" is used to search only childs of the given tag. "Element" is used to get all data from the given tag. If your XML would look like this:

```
<document>
    <object>
        <id>17</id>
        <userID>128321</userID>
        <approved>1</approved>
        <reason>Test "Declined"</reason>
    </object>
    <object>
        <id>18</id>
        <userID>128321</userID>
        <approved>2</approved>
        <reason>Test "Confirmed"</reason>
    </object>
<document>
```

Using the above method, you'll be able to initiate a List or Array with the id, userID, approved and reason values.

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Dear regards,
Björn